# How to make Pagination work in Webgrids in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, pagination, webgrid

I have an MVC/asp.net web app where users (among other things) can modify content in a database. Everything is working fine, except that when I add more than 10 items to my webgrid, it adds a second page that throws an error.

Just for clarification in the code, the content that can be updated belongs to an Application and is written in a specified language.

**MyController:** In summation, the user selects the Application and Language they want to update content for. We then connect to the DB and search it for all content that matches the Application ID and the language LCID. If it matches, 'the Factory' passes it back as an object, otherwise it comes back null. If null, it doesn't get added. If there is any content at all available, it creates a temp session and passes it to the View controller (this way the URL changes, not just the view).

```
public ActionResult Content(ContentCreator contentCreator)
    {
        consoleEntities db = new consoleEntities();
        List<translation_contents> possibleContents = db.translation_contents.ToList(); //get a list of ALL the translation contents
        List<WebGrid> webGrids = new List<WebGrid>(); //the passable object to populate the table in UpdateContent view


        foreach (translation_contents contentToCheck in possibleContents)
        {
            //the FactoryOfWebGrids will check if the contentToCheck AppName and language match what the user provided.
            //if it matches, it will pass back a webGrid object to add to the list. If it doesnt, it will pass back a Null which is not added.                    
            WebGrid Factory = FactoryOfWebGrids(contentToCheck, contentCreator.SelectedApplication, contentCreator.CurrentLanguage);
            if (Factory != null)
            {
                webGrids.Add(Factory);
            }
        }

        //If there are no webgrids, do not go to the ContentUpdate View
        if (webGrids.Count == 0)
        {
            ContentCreator passBack = CreateContentObject(); //needs a new ContentCreator object to reload the Contents View
            ViewBag.Message = "No Content to Display. Please try again.";
            return View("Content", passBack);
        }
        else
        {
            Session["webGrids"] = webGrids;
            TempData["passableWebGrid"] = webGrids;


            return Redirect("ContentUpdate");
        }

    }

    public ActionResult ContentUpdate()
    {

        List<WebGrid> webGrids = TempData["passableWebGrid"] as List<WebGrid>;
        return View(webGrids);

    }
```

**My HTML:** Please note that this is a very condensed version, but I'll put everything GridView related in.

```
@model IEnumerable<Translation_Interface.Models.WebGrid>
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model);
 }

 ....
  <div class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="gridView">
      @grid.GetHtml(
         htmlAttributes: new { @id = "WebGrid", @class = "Grid" },
         columns: grid.Columns(
                  grid.Column(null, "Select", format: 
                  @<text>@Html.ActionLink("Select", null, null, new { @class =  "select" })</text>),
                  grid.Column("ContentTitle", "Title"),
                  grid.Column("ContentMin", "Content"),
                  grid.Column("CreatedBy", "Created By"),
                  grid.Column("LastUpdated", "Last Updated"),
                  grid.Column("Key", "ID")))
     </div>
```

The gridview works really well, and the content is passed as JSON (not shown here) just fine. But when I click to go to the second page, it throws an error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'A data source must be bound before this operation can be performed.'

So I believe what's happening is that it's trying to reload the view but on re-load, it loses the passableObject, ergo it no longer has a data source to populate the webGrid.

My question is how do I keep all the data that is available, and when I click to go to the second page, it just uses the same data/List as before?

**Notes:** I go from localhost:#####/Content/ContentUpdate => localhost:#####/Content/ContentUpdate?page=2 when the button is clicked (or at least that should theoretically be what happens, but the error throws before I get there).

**Notes:** My javascript/JQuery ONLY passes the JSON to the controller when 'select' is chosen for a row. It doesn't do anything else.

**Test Data in the GridView:**
[image: Test Data in the GridView]

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

No one answered so I just turned off pagination.

```
@model IEnumerable<Translation_Interface.Models.WebGrid>
@ {
  WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(source: Model, canPage: false);
  }
```